# Set price in all territories via App Store Connect API (for auto renewable subscription)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect, in-app-subscription

I have an app with a relatively complex subscription service (about 80 subscriptions).  I am trying to set prices for the subscriptions using the following tutorial:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/app_store/auto-renewable_subscriptions/managing_auto-renewable_subscriptions#4054523

All is good to start. I find the price that I want, then I find the equalizations for that price in all territories.  The part that I get caught up on is the following:

> To set a price point for another territory, use POST
> /v1/subscriptionPrices (Create a Subscription Price Change) again,
> replacing the subscriptionPricePoint ID with the other values you
> obtain from GET /v1/subscriptionPricePoints/{id}/equalizations (List
> All Subscription Price Point Equalizations). If the subscription is
> available in all territories, an individual POST
> /v1/subscriptionPrices call is necessary for each territory. You might
> consider automating this step.

If my app is available in all 160 territories, that is 160*80=12800 post requests that I need to make.  If I send posts as fast as possible, I am able to get a couple per second, which would still take over an hour.  However, when I do that, I get a 429 error:

> {'errors': [{'status': '429', 'code': 'RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED', 'title':
> 'The request rate limit has been reached.', 'detail': "We've received
> too many requests for this API. Please wait and try again or slow down
> your request rate."}]}

When I set the price via the app store connect GUI, I am able to set price in all territories very quickly.  I can't seem to find it, but it seems like there has to be a quicker way than doing the 12K post requests.  Is it possible to batch these post requests, or another endpoint that allows me to set all equalizations at the same time?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I also have similar requirement, In my case price for one country is enough, But when im setting price for one country using API, there status is showing as "Missing Metadata" When i add price for all countries from GUI then status change to "Ready for submit", So set price for all country is mandatory?

Answer (score 1):

**Follow the below steps:-**

1. Lest start from pricePoint: call the endpoint `/v1/subscriptions/{id}/pricePoints` to get list of all prices, filter out and keep the price id of your desired price for next endpoint.
2. Now call the endpoint `/v1/subscriptionPricePoints/{id}/equalizations` with above price id, You will receive price ids for all territories.
3. Now DONT call `/v1/subscriptionPrices` to set price, instead you need to call `/v1/subscriptions/{id}` with PATCH means you need to modify your created subscription (Using this we can add prices for all territories at once)
   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/modify_an_auto-renewable_subscription

I think the information on the Apple documentation is ambiguous or lacks clear details about this matter:

> To set a price point for another territory, use POST
> /v1/subscriptionPrices (Create a Subscription Price Change) again,
> replacing the subscriptionPricePoint ID with the other values you
> obtain from GET /v1/subscriptionPricePoints/{id}/equalizations (List
> All Subscription Price Point Equalizations). If the subscription is
> available in all territories, an individual POST
> /v1/subscriptionPrices call is necessary for each territory. You might
> consider automating this step.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/app_store/auto-renewable_subscriptions/managing_auto-renewable_subscriptions

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Which value should I pass as ID? I'm on backend and haven't had any contact with the app or the Appstore dashboard. Already tried with bundle ID and product ID but API is returning HTTP 500. Other connect API endpoints work.

Comment: The id is the identifier of the subscription, that we get upon subscription creation.

Answer (score 0):

Not a great solution, but might be the best possible given the api.  You can identify the rate limit for api requests using this:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/identifying_rate_limits

In my case, the limit was 3600, so I have to limit to 1 per second, and let it run for 3.5 hours.

Comment: It's absolutely insane how this api is designed. It's like it's written by a bunch of students in their first year, the left hand doesn't know what the right hand is doing. For in-app purchases apparently it'll apply the same price point in all other territories automatically, yet for subscriptions I have to do them one by one. Who in their right mind thought this was a good idea. It's absolutely unprofessional trash. I've used apis written by unprofessional amateurs do a better job than this piece of shit...